# How can I fix my "StreamGobbler" class to work properly with bash applications?

Tags: java

I googled a solution to run a application with keyboard input over Java, but when I try to run the **sudo apt upgrade**, the program shows all the information (including the password requirement), but it doesn't show the **Do you want to continue? [Y/n]** on the end of execution (when I run the same command on terminal, it shows the confirmation line).

**The StreamGobbler Class**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
     private final PrintStream out;
     private final Scanner inScanner;
     private final String name;

     public StreamGobbler(String name, PrintStream out, InputStream inStream) {
         this.name = name;
         this.out = out;
         inScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(inStream));
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {}
}
```

**The Bash Executor Class**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BashExecutor {
    private static PrintStream out;
    private final ArrayList<String> processLinesList = new ArrayList();
    private String lastLine = "";

    private void GetProcessResponses(final Process process, boolean showMessages, boolean keepAllLog){
        this.processLinesList.clear();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line; 
        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (showMessages) System.out.println(line);
                if (keepAllLog) this.processLinesList.add(line);
                lastLine = line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String GetLastLineExecution(){
        return this.lastLine;
    }    

    public int ExecuteBashCommand(String command, boolean isVerbose, boolean keepAllLog){
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        builder.command("bash", "-c", command);
        int errorCode = -1;
        try {
           Process proc = builder.start();
           InputStream errStream = proc.getErrorStream();
           InputStream inStream = proc.getInputStream();
           OutputStream outStream = proc.getOutputStream();


           new Thread(new StreamGobbler("in", out, inStream)).start();
           new Thread(new StreamGobbler("err", out, errStream)).start();

           out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outStream));
           GetProcessResponses(proc, isVerbose, keepAllLog);
           errorCode = proc.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        } finally {
           if (out != null) {
              out.close();
           }
        }
        return errorCode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BashExecutor bashExecutor = new BashExecutor();
        boolean isVerbose = true;
        boolean keepAllLog = false;   
        int exitValue = bashExecutor.ExecuteBashCommand("sudo apt upgrade", isVerbose, keepAllLog);
        System.out.println("Exit Value: " + exitValue);
    }

}
```

I have no idea what is wrong on those classes.

Comment: Why do you start two threads with empty `run()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to solve this problem!

On the **BashExecuter** class, i just added those lines on the **ExecuteBashCommand** function, after the line **builder.command("bash", "-c", command);**

```
builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

So, the final version of the function **ExecuteBashCommand** is:

```
public int ExecuteBashCommand(String command, boolean showMessages, boolean keepAllLog){
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    builder.command("bash", "-c", command);
    builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    int errorCode = -1;
    try {
        Process proc = builder.start();
        InputStream errStream = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStream inStream = proc.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outStream = proc.getOutputStream();

        new Thread(new StreamGobbler("in", out, inStream)).start();
        new Thread(new StreamGobbler("err", out, errStream)).start();

        out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(outStream));
        GetProcessResponses(proc, showMessages, keepAllLog);

        errorCode = proc.waitFor();
    } 
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    } 
    finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    return errorCode;
}
```